# how to edit dynamically created dom with Aloha editor?

Tags: ajax, dynamically-generated, aloha-editor

How can I get Aloha Editor to recognize and edit the dynamically created dom/content?

I usually use jquery and use '.live' or '.on' to get this to work but not sure how to using Aloha.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To create a dynamic aloha instance:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Add an editable upon clicking on some button Button
$("#Button").click(function () {
    var $ = Aloha.jQuery;
    $('#somewhere').append('<div class="editable" id="ed" ></div>');
    Aloha.jQuery('.editable').mahalo();
    Aloha.jQuery('.editable').aloha();   
});
```

Now you can simply get the content:

```
var e = Aloha.getEditableById('ed'); 
getContents();
```

I haven't tested it but it should work.